# ASP.NET Core send FormData to Controller that sends email wont post values to controller

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, email

Im new to .NET core and I am trying to know it better, right now I am trying to make a mail service on a .NET application but I cant get it to work. Previously I did a hardcoded mail funciton that worked but I read that you should hardcode passwords etc. So I gave myself this new challenge to try this out.

So I have a form where I want someone to fill in their personal information that gets sent to me, like a job offer, so that the form always sends a mail to me. This is what ive come up with but I cant get it to work.

[Project Directory][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xGVK.png

```
        HTML FORM CODE:
    
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "MailController")) {
            
                <input asp-for="_email.Name" type="text" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="Namn" required /><br />
                <input asp-for="_email.TheEmail" type="text" id="email" name="TheEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required /><br />
                <input asp-for="_email.Phone" type="text" id="phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Telefon" /><br required />
                <textarea asp-for="_email.Message" id="message" name="Message" placeholder="Message" rows="8" cols="80" required></textarea><br />
                <button class="form-button" type="submit" value="Skicka">Skicka</button>
            }

MAILCONTROLLER CODE:

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MailController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMailService mailService;
    public MailController(IMailService mailService)
    {
        this.mailService = mailService;
    }
    [HttpPost("send")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendMail([FromForm] Email request)
    {
        try
        {
            await mailService.SendEmailAsync(request);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
}

IMAILSERVICE CODE:

    public interface IMailService
    {
        Task SendEmailAsync(Email _email);
    }
}


MAILSERVICE CODE:

public class MailService : IMailService
    {
        private readonly MailSettings _mailSettings;
        public MailService(IOptions<MailSettings> mailSettings)
        {
            _mailSettings = mailSettings.Value;
        }

        public async Task SendEmailAsync(Email _email)
        {
            var email = new MimeMessage();
            email.Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(_mailSettings.Mail);
            email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(_email.ToEmail));
            email.Subject = _email.Subject;
            var builder = new BodyBuilder();
            builder.HtmlBody = _email.Message;
            email.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Connect(_mailSettings.Host, _mailSettings.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            smtp.Authenticate(_mailSettings.Mail, _mailSettings.Password);
            await smtp.SendAsync(email);
            smtp.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }


MAILSETTINGS CODE:

public class MailSettings
    {
            public string Mail { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public string Host { get; set; }
            public int Port { get; set; }
    }


STARTUP CODE: 

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.Configure<MailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));
            services.AddTransient<IMailService, Services.MailService>();
        }
```

Comment: Please describe where you went wrong.

Comment: When I submit the form I just get redirected to the top of my main page. Don't really know why and how..

Comment: `Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "Mail")`

Comment: Yinqiu thank you I missed that, I changed it but it seems to never get to the controller, I created a WriteLine inside SendMail() method in the controller but it never gets written..

Comment: You should first perform breakpoint debugging and observe whether the form is submitted to the `SendMail` method.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt get it to quiet work to publish the site to IIS, so I moved everything into a html file and work with php instead.

Comment: if you didn't throw any errors than the code probably ran.   Add try catch to your code and intercept any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "MailController") instead of Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "Mail") in my Default.aspx file.